# How to check if the key is set or not in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How to check if the key of array is set or not in PHP

How do I tell the difference between the two?

```
$a = [
          'a' => ['key' => 'value'],
          ['key' => 'value']
        ];
```

```
$a = [
          'a' => ['key' => 'value'],
          '0' => ['key' => 'value']
        ];
```

The difference is that the first one does not have an index number
but the default is 0 (['key' => 'value'])
but second has 0 index ('0' => ['key' => 'value'])

Note: It does not make sense to check whether the key is an array of numbers or not because the user may give the number.

Comment: Do you mean the second one may not have `0` as its index? These are the same currently.

Comment: What do you get when you compare the two using `===`? If they're not flagged as different, then the assumption behind your question is flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question has no answer, because the two arrays are not different: they are just different ways of writing the same thing.

To understand what I mean by that, consider this question:

> How can I tell the difference between the integer `1 + 3` and the integer `2 + 2`?

When you look at the source code of `$a = 1 + 3;` and `$a = 2 + 2;` you can see the difference; but when PHP *executes* that code, it will assign the value `4` in both cases. You can't write code that examines `$a` and works out *why* it is 4, or how it was calculated.

The same is true of the two *array literals* you show. Although they look different in your source code, once executed, PHP will assign the same *array value* in both cases.

The "canonical" version actually looks like this:

```
$a = [
   'a' => ['key' => 'value'],
   0 => ['key' => 'value']
];
```

The string `'0'` is considered the same key as the integer `0`, and entries without indexes written are assigned integer indexes in order, starting at 0.

Answer (score -1):

With array_key_exists() you can check whether a key exists.

```
$a = [
          'a' => ['key' => 'value'],
          ['key' => 'value']
        ];

var_dump(array_key_exists('0',$a));
//bool(true)

var_dump(array_key_exists(0,$a));
//bool(true)
```

The key 0 exists because the above code is only a short form of

```
$a2 = [
          'a' => ['key' => 'value'],
          '0' => ['key' => 'value']
        ];
```

If the key is a number, it is always stored as an integer.

```
foreach($a2 as $key => $val){
  var_dump($key);
}   
// string(1) "a" 
// int(0)
```

Arrays can also be compared directly. The strict comparison also shows that $a and $a2 are identical.

```
var_dump($a === $a2); //bool(true)
```

Comment: If you pay attention to the last point in the question, it is mentioned that the user may have chosen the 0 key himself, and therefore by checking the index by array_key_exists, we can not be sure that in the case of numeric indexes, it is set by the user or by PHP Auto choised.

Comment: There are no differences between the arrays here for PHP. It was my aim to prove that. It's just different spellings.
Neither can I tell with PHP whether $arr = array(); or $arr = []; was written.